# import a stdout of wasm file created from go fileand fetch in nodejs

Tags: node.js, go, import, webassembly

I have the following go file converted to xxx.wasm. I have the executable of main.go build but it cannot be built in every machine this package is imported.

Following is the wasm code i am using

`index.js`

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const wasmBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./xxx.wasm');
WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBuffer).then(wasmModule => {
  // Exported function live under instance.exports
  const { GetCalculations } = wasmModule.instance.exports;
  const result = GetCalculations([]) // [some arguments.............]);

  // const go = wasmModule.instance.exports;
  // const result = go.GetCalculations([]) // [some arguments.............]);

  // const go = wasmModule.instance.exports;
  // const result = go([]) // [some arguments.............]);

  console.log(result); // Outputs: some string

  console.log(/* Alternatively I also want a way to print the result of running the main functions result in the console.log */)

});
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func GetCalculations(args []string) string {
    // my code here using args
    return "some string"
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args
    resultstr := GetCalculations(args)
    fmt.Println(resultstr)
}
```

There are two things.

1. How do i use the GetCalculations function that is passed an array of arguments as sting
2. How do i use the result of running the main function (the result of executable)

i am getting following error when running the above `index.js` code

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Imports argument must be present and must be an object]

Node.js v21.6.1
```

i get the results when running the built executable from my console .

the following code also gives error

`index.mjs` run as `ode --experimental-modules --experimental-wasm-modules ./demos/demos.wasm.mjs`

```
import { GetCalculations } from '../xxx.wasm';
console.log(GetCalculations(["", ""]))
```

error

```
(node:17464) ExperimentalWarning: Importing WebAssembly modules is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:844
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
        ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'gojs' imported from C:\Users\ganes\OneDrive\Documents\projects\gouuidjs\gouuid.wasm
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:844:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:901:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1131:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v21.6.1
```